# Is it safe to update Firestore records client side?

Tags: express, security, google-cloud-firestore

I have been reading about Firestore and it looks like a lot of the libraries are client side. I'm interested in doing it client side but it seems manipulable.

If I authenticate as user A, it seems as though I can go in and make a call as if I am any user, e.g. user B, C, etc.

Is it necessary to have middleware that would receive a token and convert it to a uid (this abstracted away from the user) and then safely update that uid's records?

Am I missing anything where I see the loop holes in client-side Firestore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Firestore you'd use its server-side security rules to ensure users can only access data that they're authorized for. Since these run on the server, there is no way for a regular user of your app to bypass them.

Instead of reiterating a lot of information about them, I recommend you check out the [documentation on Firestore's server-side security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview), as well as this more general [documentation about Firebase's approach to server-side security](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules).

Comment: I'm going to dive into those, thanks for sharing. I'm curious from a high level view, if a user creates a "post" which is essentially a document in a collection called "posts" is it possible for me to restrict data added to that document such that it matches specific criteria? For example, all posts have an owner/createdBy field. I would want to restrict user Frank to be the only user who can post with createdBy == Frank. This will let me wrap my head around what's possible while reading, thanks again!

Comment: Yup, that (and much more) all sounds possible. I suggest first reading the docs, then giving it a try, and if you get stuck, check out some [questions about Firestore's server-side security rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-firestore+firebase-security-rules), you can do quite a bit with it.